# ECS logging (awslogs driver) only logging apache server startup logs to cloudwatch, no error.log & no access.log

Tags: apache, docker, logging, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have the problem that my ECS logs (awslogs driver) are not working as expected. In Cloudwatch I'm only seeing the server startup logs & not the useful logs from the apache (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` & `/var/log/apache2/access.log`)

I have a docker multicontainer setup with one container running the apache server & the other container running PHP-FPM. My container logs on cloudwatch look like this:

Apache-Container:

```
23:35:39 *** Running /etc/my_init.d/02_init.sh...
23:35:39 Starting Apache
23:35:39 * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
23:35:39 /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 87: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
23:35:39 Setting ulimit failed. See README.Debian for more information.
23:35:40 *** Running /etc/rc.local...
23:35:40 *** Booting runit daemon...
23:35:40 *** Runit started as PID 225
23:35:40 Oct 25 22:35:40 apache-container syslog-ng[231]: syslog-ng starting up; version='3.5.6'
2019-10-26 00:17:01
Oct 25 23:17:01 apache-container CRON[947]: (root) CMD ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
...
07:35:16 tail: '/var/log/syslog' has been replaced; following new file
...
```

FPM-Container:

```
...
10:25:23 172.x.x.x - 27/Okt/2019:09:25:23 +0000 "GET /app.php" 200
10:25:25 172.x.x.x - 27/Okt/2019:09:25:24 +0000 "GET /app.php" 200
...
```

I've checked various forums & online resources. As I understood it right I just need to symlink my logs to STDOUT/STDERR or even better to `/proc/self/fd/1` & `/proc/self/fd/2`  like this:

```
ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/access.log
ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

I've tried to link the logs in my `.Dockerfile` via the `RUN` command & also during runtime, but no success. I see that my logs are showing up correctly in the log files before linking them. I've also tried things like `echo "test stderr logs" >> /dev/stderr` or `echo "test stdout logs" >> /dev/stdout` inside & outside the containers, but nothing showing up in the cloudwatch logs. When I try `docker logs MY_DOCKER_CONTAINER_ID` I get: `Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support reading`.

Maybe I'm missing some basic knowledge here. I see that `syslog` is in my environment/base image (maybe i need to merge syslog & apache logs?) and that the PHP-FPM-container is logging 200's but only to the `app.php` even though I would like to know the exact path of the accessed url.

Comment: How you start these process in Dockerfile?

Comment: @Adiii the .Dockerfile gets builds via Bitbucket pipelines and the command I run like this. But I've also tried to run those commands via SSH without the RUN statement and without success:
`RUN mkdir -p /var/log/apache2/ && touch /var/log/apache2/access.log && ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/apache2/access.log`
 
and 

`RUN mkdir -p /var/log/apache2/ && touch /var/log/apache2/error.log && ln -sf /proc/1/fd/2 /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: pls show dockerfile with entrypoint and CMD

Comment: Hey thx for the response. If I remember it right, the problem was, that all of my output was redirected to syslog & there was a misconfiguration in my syslog config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thx for the responses. If I remember it right, the problem was, that all of my output was redirected to syslog & there was a misconfiguration in my syslog config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in your docker-compose used by ECS to use the cloudwatch logging driver like so:

```
version: '2'
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: .
    logging:
      driver: awslogs
      options:
        awslogs-group: "/my/log/group"
        awslogs-region: "us-west-2"
        awslogs-stream-prefix: some-prefix
```

This should cause /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr to appear in CloudWatch.  You can find more information on the logging driver options on the [Docker page](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/).

Comment: Hey thx for the response. If I remember it right, the problem was, that all of my output was redirected to syslog & there was a misconfiguration in my syslog config.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using supervisord and rsyslog to log apache, php errors, and application logs to stdout/stderr, since some things have issues writing to pipes.